# Code::Blocks with MinGW compiler - fprintf results in empty file

Tags: c, windows, mingw, codeblocks

I have so far only used Linux to do coding (gcc and command line with Kate, basically). I want to get into programming in windows because all the more powerful machines I have access to run Win7.

So I downloaded codeblocks and minGW. Hello world runs fine, but when it comes to printing something to file, it just gives me an empty file. Am I making a newbie mistake? It created testfile.txt, but the file is empty after execution.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *test;
    if (test=fopen("testfile.txt","w")==NULL)
    {
            printf("Open Failed\n");
            abort();
    }
    int i=9;
    fprintf(test,"This is a test %d\n",i);
    fclose(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect :

```
if (test=fopen("testfile.txt","w")==NULL)
```

Your if statement should be:

```
 if ((test=fopen("testfile.txt","w"))==NULL)
```

So the file *"testfile.txt"* will be opened correctly and you will get the expected output :

```
This is a test 9
```

Comment: Newbie mistake indeed. Thanks.